# python match capital and small letters without using lower or upper

Tags: python, regex

How can I make a string case insensitive so that when tested against capital or small letters returns true every time.

for example is there a way to achieve the following:

```
>>> someregex('y') == 'Y'
True
>>> someregex('y') == 'y'
True
```

what would the someregex look like ? Note that in my program changes only to the left part of the expressions is allowed and I cannot simply use .lower() on the right side.

Thanks

Comment: The regex would be `^[yY]$`

Comment: `re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: You *can* use `upper` and `lower` on only the left side by doing something like `if any(c == right_side for c in [leftside.upper(), leftside.lower()])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you want some subclass of a string which is case insensitive when comparing.

```
class CaseInsensitiveString(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        This overloads the == operator to make it perform a case-insensitive comparison
        """
        return self.lower() == other.lower()
```

Using that subclass:

```
>>> CaseInsensitiveString('y') == 'Y'
True

>>> CaseInsensitiveString('y') == 'y'
True
```

Comment: Rather than `str.lower`, consider [`str.casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) because "it is intended to remove all case distinctions in a string". `str.lower` does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that with the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('^[yY]$', 'y')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='y'>
>>> re.match('^[yY]$', 'Y')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='Y'>
>>> re.match('^[yY]$', 'X')# something that doesn't match gives None
```